# Error in MySQL Syntax using select statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hi can you please help me in this, I don't know where my error is. 
here is my code:

```
    $capacitance =@mysql_query ("SELECT DISTINCT wwpn,  SUBSTR(val, 1, LENGTH(val) / 2) as capacitor,
                             SUBSTR(val, LENGTH(val) / 2+1) as capasitance
                             FROM   bom_csv where boardnumber ='$board' and qty<>'' and qty !='qty'");
    @mysql_query($capacitance,$connect)or die("Failed to execute query:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($capacitance))
     {
         $capacitor = $row['capacitor'];
         $capacitance =$row['capasitance'];
         $adi_pn = $row['wwpn'];
     }
```

and the error while I am executing it by php:

```
Failed to execute query:
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #4' at line 1
1064
```

Comment: Please show your relevant PHP code

Comment: Have you tried doing it in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Your first `mysql_query` is returning a resource (a resultset) and assigning it to `$capacitance`. When you execute `mysql_query` again in the next line, `$capacitance`, a resource, is turned into a string - `"Resource #4"`, likely - which is not a proper SQL.

Also note that "[Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) doesn't go to my school" is not necessarily true: escape your strings properly.

```
$capacitance = @mysql_query ("SELECT DISTINCT wwpn,  SUBSTR(val, 1, LENGTH(val) / 2) as capacitor,
                             SUBSTR(val, LENGTH(val) / 2+1) as capasitance
                             FROM   bom_csv where boardnumber ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($board) . "' and qty<>'' and qty !='qty'", $connect)
or die("Failed to execute query:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());
while ...
```